# Simplifying tables (squashing them!) in R- basic q

Tags: r

I have a basic q I would like a quick R solution in...

I have a tab delimited table with multiple rows, but I want to "squash" all rows into one... for example:

```
name   day  red  blue   orange  black
bill    1   yes         
bill    2        yes        
bill    3                        yes
bill    4                 no
```

But I want the output to be independent of day:

```
name    red blue    orange  black
bill    yes yes      no      yes
```

So essentially I am squashing the table down to include all answers regardless of the day. NB: There are never any overlaps i.e. Bill will select only one colour per day.

I could do this in excel, but I'd prefer to find an R solution... happy for guidance even wrt which libraries would be useful :).

Go easy on me, I'm a clinician not a bioinformatician!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option with `dplyr`.  If the missing values are `""`, after grouping over 'name', `summarise` by looping `across` the columns and get the elements that are not a blank (`.[. != ""]`)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(name) %>%
   summarise(across(red:black, ~ .[.!= '']))
```

Or if the missing values are `NA`

```
df1 %>%
     group_by(name) %>%
     summarise(across(red:black, ~ .[!is.na(.)]))
```

If there are more than one non-missing element, the above output will be a `list` column.  Instead, we can also `paste` it together

```
df1 %>%
     group_by(name) %>%
     summarise(across(red:black, ~ toString(.[!is.na(.)])))
```

If there are both `NA` and `""`, an option is to convert the `""` to `NA` and then use `is.na` or `complete.cases` or with `na.omit`

```
df1 %>%
 group_by(name) %>%
 summarise(across(red:black, ~ toString(na.omit(na_if(., "")))))
```

Comment: you star! There is more than one non-missing element so the only one that worked was your third solution. Not sure where I go from here turning the output into a readable dataframe though... apologies if I'm being stupid!

Comment: @lecb For the other two, it will be `list` columns

Comment: One last q (apologies)... all the character values seem to have 2 trailing commas after the text.. but only after executing the code... ?!

Comment: @lecb Is it from the last block of code.  `toString(c('a', 'b'))` converts to a single string with `,` separated

Comment: Yes. I'm assuming it is when the values are pasted together it accepts a missing value...

Comment: @lecb  I think you have `""` as missing values.  Probably you can change it to `toString(.[. !=""])`

Comment: @lecb when you have `""`, it happens i.e. `toString(c('a', '', 'b'))`.  `!is.na` works when the missing value is `NA`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225066/discussion-between-lecb-and-akrun).

Answer (score 0):

In base R, you could use `aggregate` and select non-blank values for each name.

```
aggregate(cbind(red,blue,orange,black)~name, df, function(x) toString(x[x!='']))

#  name red blue orange black
#1 bill yes  yes     no   yes
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(name = c("bill", "bill", "bill", "bill"), day = 1:4, 
    red = c("yes", "", "", ""), blue = c("", "yes", "", ""), 
    orange = c("", "", "", "no"), black = c("", "", "yes", ""
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```